# Authenticating against Azure AD with Desktop App

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I wrote desktop app that authenticates against Azure AD using MSAL.NET in C#.
It is a client for my web app that has API. I wrote this app in addition to having web UI.
Web UI with ASP.NET Core 7 successfully authenticates against Azure AD and then calls API.

At this point I haven't deployed the web app to Azure - it is running locally using IIS (maybe Kester). So now when I run the desktop client I successfully authenticate and receive `AccessToken`. However, when I call API with this URL:
https://localhost:7262/api/v1/doc/indexes I get HTML response like this:

[image]

Now, I checked the HWT `AccessToken` and it looks OK,
I have Application ID URI defined along with the read and write scopes.
Redundant to say that all other IDs like `ClientID`, `TenantID`, etc, are correct - otherwise I would not get `AccessToken` back.

I am suspecting that something is wrong with redirection. Somehow the above API redirects the API to [maybe] login page. I tried to use named HttpClient with `AllowForwarding` set to false, but then it responds with code 302 "Found".

My redirection URL:

> "CallbackPath":
> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"

Then I got desktop sample app from Azure that automatically populated with my account and calls MS Graph API and it work. However, when I replace it with my API (above) it give me the same HTML response "We can't sign you in".

Or maybe, I should not expect this to work when web app with API is running locally.
Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my simple call:

```
public async Task<HttpApiResponse?> GetIndexesAsync(string url, string accessToken)
        {
          using(Log.VerboseCall())
          {
            try
            {
                using (var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient()) // "NoRedirectClient"))
                //using (var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                    // Send POST request
                    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // Handle success (200–299 status codes)
                        return new HttpApiResponse(true, responseContent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return ReturnErrorByCode(response.StatusCode, responseContent);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex);
            }

        return null;
    }
}
```